# Segfault when assigning the same variable to each other in a do loop

Tags: fortran, gfortran, urlencode

We are developing a function to encode URL in Fortran.
`urlencode_one_Text` contains the decimal value of a string and returns it as url encoding

The error is `Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference`.

This is not a compilation error, but a run-time error.
Is there any way to resolve this error?

I'm staring at line 22, and the code looks like it's written correctly.
I want to divide x by 16, but I can't.

Environment: windows 10 ,   GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0,  PowerShell  ,  vim,  Stored Encodings utf-8, Fortran 95,  No additional options in gfortran

```
program main
implicit none
call urlencode_one_Text(8552931)
end program main
subroutine urlencode_one_Text(x)
implicit none

integer            ::  x, remainder = 0, intlen = 0
character(len=10)  ::  urlencode(10) = ''
character(len=1)   ::  temp_character = ''
data remainder/ 0/
data intlen/    10/
urlencode(10)   =  '\0'

 
do
 print *, 2
 intlen     =  intlen - 1
 print *, 2
 remainder  =  mod(x , 16)
 print *, 2
 x          =  x / 16
 print *, 2

 select case (intlen)
 case (1)
   intlen        =  intlen - 1
   urlencode(1)  =  '%'
 case (4)
   intlen        =  intlen - 1
   urlencode(4)  =  '%'
 case (7)
   intlen        =  intlen - 1
   urlencode(7)  =  '%'
 end select

 select case (remainder)
 case (10)
   print *, 4
   urlencode(intlen) = 'A'
 case (11)
   urlencode(intlen) = 'B'
 case (12)
   urlencode(intlen) = 'C'
 case (13)
   urlencode(intlen) = 'D'
 case (14)
   urlencode(intlen) = 'E'
 case (15)
   urlencode(intlen) = 'F'
 case default
   print *, 5
   write(temp_character, *) remainder
   urlencode(intlen) = temp_character
   temp_character = ''
   print *, 6
 end select

 remainder  =  0
 if ((16 .ge. x) .or. (10 .eq. intlen)) then
   print *, 7
   exit
 end if
end do

print *, urlencode
 
return
end subroutine urlencode_one_Text
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Enable all compiler debug options. Use `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all` and re-compile and re-run.

Comment: With `x = ...` you are trying to change the value of the constant `8552931`.  That's not allowed.

Comment: How do I allow it? x = ...

Comment: The fortran tag has been added...
I referred to "gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all" and added additional options, but the result did not change.

Comment: The answer to the linked question explains how to modify your code by creating a version of the input argument which you can modify.